# Remove Pair of XML Tags

Tags: xml, tags, redundancy, text-editor

Is there a fast visual way of deleting unwanted XML tags. It's just very time consuming having to delete both the beginning and the end tag. I have some XML code which I need to clean up for redundant nodes which are causing an error. My issue is very synonymous with having this in HTML:

From:

```
   <b><b>double bolded</b></b>
```

to this:

```
   <b>double bolded</b>
```

I tried finding something that could do this in Notepad++ but couldn't find anything. I found some scripts that might do something similar, but it's important that I can control it manually because there are times where a double nesting is required in my code.

EDIT:

Here's a sample piece of XML which I would be formatting manually:

```
<displayFormula>
  <mrow>
    <mrow>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mrow>
        <mi mvar="S">{Selling Price}</mi>
        <mo>×</mo>
        <mi mvar="x">{hypo quant}</mi>
      </mrow>
    </mrow>
  </mrow>
</displayFormula>
<displayFormula>
```

(The above sample uses MathML)
The multiple nests of `<mrow>` are redundant and cause errors while parsing. There are times where you would want `<mrow>` together though like in this structure:

```
<displayFormula>
  <mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mi mvar="S">{Selling Price}</mi>
        <mo>×</mo>
        <mi mvar="x">{hypo quant}</mi>
      </mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mi mvar="S">{Selling Price}</mi>
        <mo>×</mo>
        <mi mvar="x">{hypo quant}</mi>
      </mrow>
  </mrow>
</displayFormula>
```

I noticed that Notepad++ automatically highlights both the open and close tags when one is selected and I was just wondering if there was a way to delete those highlighted tags.

Comment: In notepad++ you simply replace '<b><b>' with '<b>' and same for closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds ideal for a little regex. The following should work for simple tags like in your HTML example but will need some work to make it work for more complex mark-up that contains attributes for example.

Search:

```
(<([^>]+)>)\1
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use TopStyle.  http://www.topstyle4.com/

It has a feature that allows you to `find` and then `replace on prompt`, so it will find all the instances and then go through each one to see if you do or do not want to replace it (either with something or a blank space [nothing])

[image]